# SSL connection error when connecting to MySQL, using JDBC

Tags: mysql, mariadb, java

The problem that we are facing is well documented in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189756/warning-about-ssl-connection-when-connecting-to-mysql-database)

We started facing this issue upon transitioning from `MySQL 5.6.51` to `MySQL 8.0.27`.
The fix that is suggested works for us but we have an issue in that we don’t want to update the Java source files to change, for example, from

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Peoples
```

to

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Peoples?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34449182

---

**Question:** Is there some change that we can make to the execution environment of our new target (`Ubuntu kernel version 5.4.0-91`) such that we need not make changes to the existing Java code?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71297643/20860